# python script doesn't work properly under scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

I have a program on Windows Server 2012 that:
-reads sql query from text file in the same location
-imports helper functions from file in the same location
-executes query on sql server (in the same network) and saves the results
-creates a google spreadsheet from the results (using API credencials that are in the same location)

When I log in to tthe server and execute the file in cmd: python myscript.py everything is fine. However when I try to do the same from Task Scheduler it fails. I get 0x1 error.

This is what I put in my Scheduler actions:

- program/script - quoted full path to python.exe (which is in Anaconda folder)
- Arguments - quoted full path to myscript.py
- Start in - blank

I have tried running it as myself, SYSTEM, Administrators. Also tried Highest priveleges and user logged on or not options... Also followed another solution on SO that recommended running cmd and then "/c python full/path/to/myscript.py" But it's always the same.

It´s very frustrating. I realize it's not strictly coding related issue but I am sure many python programmers had it.

Comment: Please show us some code, a log excerpt or basically anything that could help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Maurice Thanks. I don't think it's a coding issue since it works properly when run manually.... When Scheduler runs it, in task history it says it's been finished successfully (with 0x1 message) and there are no exclamation marks that would suggest different problems. Are you referring to these logs? I am just judging it´s been unsuccessful because there is no expected result.

Comment: Have you checked/ticked 'run whether user is logged in or not'?

Comment: Would it be possible to put the call to python in a .bat file in the Anaconda folder and test it there, then mark the scheduler 'Edit action' to be 'Start in' that same Anaconda folder?

Comment: @BillBell: Not sure I understand. I have moved my scripts to Anaconda folder and created .bat file powershell python myscript.py and it did the job. Is that what you meant? What am I supposed to do with my .bat file?  I don't want to put all my scheduled scripts to Anaconda folder.

Comment: I didn't mean move all your Python scripts to Anaconda, just to try *executing* a .ps1 or a .bat from there as a way of eliminating possible problems owing to unavailability of modules, etc there. Then with 'Edit' set to 'Start in' Anaconda, run the .ps1 or .bat file and it should be in the same environment as when you executed it. The Python would be executed from a .ps1 or .bat.

Comment: @BillBell: What I did was creating a .bat file with "powershell python "full/path/to/myscript.py" in Anaconda folder. Then I reference to this .bat file in Scheduler as Program/Script with argument being myscript.py. And it worked! However when I put Anaconda folder in 'Start in' I get error 'Invalid directory'. Another issue I have now is that it doesn't find the .txt file with a query that is in the same folder as myscript.py.

Comment: Does it mean I have to create .bat file in Acaconda folder for each automated process?

Comment: I don't know why it should be necessary but ... if it works? About your other issue: you could try writing stderr to a file for examination.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the same error when starting non-python tasks with scheduler?
If not - I would try to install clear Python and create new schedule .bat file with

```
powershell C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\file.py
pause
```

Comment: No, other non-python tasks run OK. I have tried installing clear python and executing .bat file, but I can do the same from Anaconda folder as BillBell suggested above. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I'm curious about why you should wrap the execution of python with a call to powershell. Would you please explain?

Comment: @BillBell I've just copy-pasted first founded .bat file examle. So of course cmd can be used insted_